# How to pass a DataFrame column as an argument in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, parameter-passing, filtering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wimFh.png)
Check the distribution of a specific value like the number of times the weather was exactly Cloudy in the given column. Feel free to check on other values. You can check it by calling the function clear with respective parameters.

```
#Importing the modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode 

weather = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ",", delimiter = None)
#code to check distribution of variable
def clear(df,col,val):
    """ Check distribution of variable
    df,col,val
    This function accepts a dataframe,column(feature) and value which returns count of the value,
    containing the value counts of a variable(value_counts)

Keyword arguments:
df - Pandas dataframe
col - Feature of the datagrame
val - value of the feature

Returns:
value_counts - Value count of the feature 
"""
        
value_counts = df[(df.col == val)]     # filtering dataframe
print(len(value_counts))
```

clear(weather,weather.Weather,'Cloudy')    # calling function clear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just pass on the name of the column - instead of the entire column:

```
def clear(df, column_name, column_value):
    value_counts = df.loc[(df[column_name] == column_value)]     # filtering dataframe
    return len(value_counts)
```